# ionic - Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Currently working with PDF-Viewer with Angular and Firebase, I keep getting the runtime error "Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'".

Does anyone know why this is? Here is my dependency list:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "4.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
"@angular/http": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"@types/html2canvas": "^0.5.35",
"@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
"cordova-android": "6.3.0",
"cordova-pdf-generator": "^1.9.3",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"cordova-browser": "5.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.0.19",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
"firebase": "^4.6.1",
"html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
"ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"jspdf": "^1.3.5",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "5.4.3",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
"typescript": "2.3.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
  "cordova-pdf-generator": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "browser",
  "android"
]
}
```

I've tried rolling back dependencies to earlier states but that seems to just cause more problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

one area ive used pdf viewer

```
<div id="pdfPreview">
        <pdf-viewer [src]="srcPdf"  [render-text]="true" [page]="1" [original-size]="false"
        style="display: block;"
        ></pdf-viewer>

    <!--<img 

   src="assets/img/45SeroAhRyuPNagS090v_
  DM2AjubpQ1SXM2UlmWa8_PeterWyrostekTicketApp
  eal123456.jpg" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;margin-
 left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />-->
</div>
```

Another area where im using pdf viewer:

```
   <div>
    <pdf-viewer [src]="srcPdf"  [render-text]="true" [page]="1" [original-size]="false"
    style="display: block;"
    ></pdf-viewer>
    <!--<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, img" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />-->
</div>
```

error log:

```
syntaxError@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:94243:39
parse@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:105481:30
_compileTemplate@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:119675:44
forEach@[native code]
_compileComponents@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:119594:26
http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:119481:37
compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:119409:64
_bootstrapModuleWithZone@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:4893:43
http://localhost:8107/build/main.js:3904:124
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:55:34
webpackJsonpCallback@http://localhost:8107/build/vendor.js:26:42
global code@http://localhost:8107/build/main.js:1:13
```

So if I'm reading this correctly theres a syntax error in vendor.js? I thought that was auto generated when building?

Comment: Where are you getting the error message?

Comment: You need to show us where did you use the pdf-viewer in your code.

Comment: @ObsidianAge as soon as the android application loads.

Comment: I meant what *line* of code does it say the error message originates from? As in, how is that plugin getting referenced? You can step through the error with the F12 Developer Tools to see exactly when it is getting thrown.

Comment: @Melchia updated

Comment: you have to share the code for your component and your Module to be able to answer this question. Package.json is probably not the source of issue. still I provided best answer with the given info

Comment: @ObsidianAge updated -- so is there a syntax error in vendor.js? i thought that was autogenerated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue rises when you don't import properly the module in this case **PdfViewerModule**
Like this scenario

```
-- app.module.ts --> move PdfViewerModule here if you're not sure.
---- sub1.module.ts --> move PdfViewerModule import here can work too.
------ sub1_1.module.ts --> Maybe you imported the module here & you use it somewhere else out the scope of this submodule.
```

Either way this an example how to import **PdfViewerModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. The PdfViewerModule must have gotten deleted when we did a huge merge and I didn't even think to check it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons why this happens:

1. your component is not added to declarations in your module.(directly or by importing other modules) so
   Angular can not figure out what Inputs your component can take.
2. Your component does not have a 'src' Input parameter.

in your case looks like you have forgot to import the module in your application module. 
https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule],
```